# How do I store 'date' in SQL Server 2005 using C# query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

an error while storing date in DB (SQL server 2005) using C#
I am using,

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Now;

insert into mytablename (appdate) values('"+mydate.ToShortDateString()+"');
```

bt its showing error when I run the query

also tried,

`mydate.ToShortDateString().ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` in C# , still showing error in editor only.

How do I store 'date' in SQL Server 2005 using C# query

Comment: Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)! Do NOT simply concatenate SQL Statements and values!

Comment: What error are you getting? Also you should consider using paramaterised queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameterized SQL, and set the value into the parameter:

```
string sql = "insert into tablename (appdate) values (@appdate)";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@appdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value
            = DateTime.Now;
        int rowsInserted = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // TODO: Validation of result (you'd expect it to be 1)
    }
}
```

You should *always* use parameterized SQL when you have data to include in the request to the database. This avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and data conversion issues, as well as keeping your code cleaner.

You should also consider whether you really want it to be the *local* date/time or the *UTC* date/time. For example, you might want to use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your query tries to insert a string in a DateTime field. And of course it doesn't work.
The correct way to insert is through a parametrized query like this

```
string insertSQL = "insert into mytablename (appdate) values(@dt)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", mydate);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here I assume that the connection is already initialized and opened

Comment: You are mistaken, the way to write a date literal in a query has the same syntax as a string, so that works just fine as long as the date format is what the database expects.

Comment: thank you all for reply, but my query works when I am using SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Guffa, the key is 'what the database expects', a parameter will avoid this. Right? And this is probably the reason of the failure with the new database.

Comment: @Steve: You are missing the point. The reason that it doesn't work is not that it is in the form of a string, it's the format of the date in the string.